# Why does Regex finditer only return the first result

Tags: python, regex, string, match

My string is a transcript, I want to capture the speaker, specifically their second name (Which needs to only match when fully capitalised)
Additionally, I want to match their speech until the next speaker begins, I want to loop this process over a huge text file eventually.

The problem is the match only returns one match object, even though there are two different speakers. Also I have tried online regex tester with the python flavor however, they return very different results (not sure why?).

```
str = 'Senator BACK\n (Western Australia) (21:15): This evening I had the pleasure (...) Senator         DAY\n (South Australia) (21:34): Well, what a week it h(...) ' 

pattern = re.compile("(:?(Senator|Mr|Dr)\s+([A-Z]{2,})\s*(\(.+?\))\s+(\(\d{2}:\d{2}\):)(.*))(?=Senator)")

for match in re.finditer(pattern, str):
    print(match)
```

I want 2 match objects, both objects having a group for there surname and their speech. It's important to note also I have used Regex debuggers online however the python flavor gives different results to Python on my terminal.

Comment: Your regex matches only if the substring is followed by the word "Senator" (because of `"(?=Senator)"`). The second substring in your example does not match because there is no "Senator" after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the regex into:

```
(:?(Senator|Mr|Dr)\s+([A-Z]{2,})\s*(\(.+?\))\s+(\(\d{2}:\d{2}\):)(.*))(?=Senator|$)
```

demo: https://regex101.com/r/gJDaWM/1/

With your current regex, you are enforcing the condition that each match must be followed by `Senator` through the positive lookahead.

You might actually have to change the positive lookahead into:

```
(?=Senator|Mr|Dr|$)
```

if you want to take into account `Mr` and `Dr` on top of `Senator`.